# LZ4 compression library in android app

Tags: java, android, lz4

How do I use LZ4 compression library in my android application...

The main issue I'm facing is when i try to export a signed application package, the error which comes is

**Warning: net.jpountz.util.UnsafeUtils: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe**

When I directly run the application in my device, there is no issue, this error comes only when I try to export the application.

Comment: I've added a exclude command in proguard for the following package.